# How to use a non-ASCII symbol (e.g. £) in an R package function?

Tags: r, warnings, package, ascii

I have a simple function in one of my R packages, with one of the arguments `symbol = "£"`:

```
formatPound <- function(x, digits = 2, nsmall = 2, symbol = "£"){ 
  paste(symbol, format(x, digits = digits, nsmall = nsmall)) 
}
```

But when running `R CMD check`, I get this warning:

```
* checking R files for non-ASCII characters ... WARNING
Found the following files with non-ASCII characters:
  formatters.R
```

It's definitely that `£` symbol that causes the problem. If I replace it with a legitimate ASCII character, like `$`, the warning disappears.

**Question: How can I use `£` in my function argument, without incurring a `R CMD check` warning?**

Comment: Maybe by specifying the encoding argument, and setting either latin1 or utf-8 ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looks like "Writing R Extensions" covers this in Section 1.7.1 ["Encoding Issues"](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Encoding-issues).

---

One of the recommendations in this page is to use the Unicode encoding `\uxxxx`. Since £ is Unicode 00A3, you can use:

```
formatPound <- function(x, digits=2, nsmall=2, symbol="\u00A3"){
  paste(symbol, format(x, digits=digits, nsmall=nsmall))
}


formatPound(123.45)
[1] "£ 123.45"
```

Comment: Thank you. This is really helpful. I have edited your answer to be more specific in its advice. (As an aside, googling for this warning message simply results in lists of packages with this warning!).

Comment: The problem with this approach is that e.g. roxygen2 v6.0.1 generates Rd files that later cause errors in R CMD check (non-ASCII chars). See my workaround below.

Answer (score 6):

As a workaround, you can use `intToUtf8()` function:

```
# this causes errors (non-ASCII chars)
f <- function(symbol = "➛")

# this also causes errors in Rd files (non-ASCII chars)
f <- function(symbol = "\u279B")

# this is ok
f <- function(symbol = intToUtf8(0x279B))
```

Comment: I also found out that `testthat` package has problems running tests that contain UTF-8 chars.