# Using non-ASCII characters inside functions for packages

Tags: r, string, unicode, ascii

I'm trying to write a function equivalent to `scales::dollar` that adds a pound (£) symbol to the beginning of a figure. Since the scales code is so robust, I've used it as a framework and simply replaced the $ for the £.

A stripped-down function example:

```
pounds<-function(x) paste0("£",x)
```

When I run a CHECK I get the following:

```
Found the following file with non-ASCII characters:
  pounds.R
Portable packages must use only ASCII characters in their R code,
except perhaps in comments.
Use \uxxxx escapes for other characters.
```

Looking through the *Writing R extensions* guide it doesn't give a lot of help (IMO) on how to resolve this issue.  It mentions the \uxxxx and says it refers to Unicode characters.

Looking up unicode characters yields me the code `&#163` but the guidance I can find for `\uxxxx` is minimal and relates to Java on W3schools.

My question is thus:

**How do you implement the usage of non-unicode characters in R functions using the \uxxxx escapes and how does the usage affect the display of such characters after the function has been used?**

Comment: For reference - see this question that is almost identical: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11452796/602276

Comment: Cheers @Andrie - not sure how I didn't find that in my googling the first time round. Karsten adds valuable information on how to identify what the unicode should be - I'd suggest marking as duplicate otherwise.

Comment: Since this question also has answer, we can't close as duplicate.  There is a process for merging similar questions, but I don't have time to do this.  For me, it's good enough that the questions are linked.  If somebody else wants to initiate the merging, that's fine too.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For the \uxxxx escapes, you need to know the hexadecimal number of your character. You can determine it using `charToRaw`:

```
sprintf("%X", as.integer(charToRaw("£")))
[1] "A3"
```

Now you can use this to specify your non-ascii character. Both `\u00A3` and `£` represent the same character.

Another option is to use `stringi::stri_escape_unicode`:

```
library(stringi)
stringi::stri_escape_unicode("➛")
# "\\u279b"
```

This informs you that `"\u279b"` represents the character `"➛"`.

Comment: This gives `sprintf("%X", as.integer(charToRaw("➛"))) # "E2" "9E" "9B` for `➛`. How to proceed then?

Comment: Edited answer for this case. Don't know why `rawToChar` does not work for your example.

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
pounds<-function(x) paste0("\u00A3",x)
```

Answer (score 7):

The **stringi** package can be useful is these situations:

```r
library(stringi)

stri_escape_unicode("£")
#> [1] "\\u00a3"
```